# Gtk+ 3 Error when compiling with OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gtk, opencv3.0

I have recently built OpenCV 3 from source on linux. I am able to successfully compile and run OpenCV programs.

I then downloaded Gtk+ 3 and all the required packages (GLib 2.52, Pango 1.40, Gdk-Pixbuf 2.36, ATK 2.24, GObject-Introspection 1.52). I am able to successfully compile and run this simple program compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 gtkexample.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gtkexample `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Source code:

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int   argc,
      char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GdkRGBA *color;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    gdk_rgba_parse(color,"(0,0,0)");
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (window),FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_override_background_color(window, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, color);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    for (int i=200;i<400;i++)
        gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW (window),i,200);



    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

After successfully compiling I try to execute my OpenCV program with Gtk+ and a FlyCapture camera and I am faced with:

> `"Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported"`

The output of `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` is:

```
-pthread -I/usr/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/include/cairo -I/usr/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/cairo -I/usr/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12
```

Output of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` is :

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

A snippet of the OpenCV program looks like:

```
#include "FlyCapture2.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudalegacy/NCVHaarObjectDetection.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaobjdetect.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace FlyCapture2;

int main( int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv); //This is where the error occurs
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (window),FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    //  ...
}
```

Compiling successfully with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 FlyCap2_to_MatImage.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -I/home/nvidia/flycapture.2.11.3.121_arm64/include -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include -o FlyCap2_to_MatImage `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lflycapture -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaobjdetect
```

My questions are:

- Could OpenCV 3 possibly be using an old version of GTK+ ?
- Will I have to rebuild OpenCV to configure with newer version of Gtk+ ?

Comment: Considering you've installed Gtk+ 3 **after** building OpenCV, it seems quite unlikely that it would be built to use that particular version of Gtk+... So, yes, you will need to rebuild it. Since you're writing your own GUI, you could probably get away with building it without any highgui backend at all.

Comment: Thanks Dan, your comment helped me out. The program will run as long as I don't link the opencv_highgui library when I compile. This is the library that is probably using the older version.

Comment: Exactly, that is the library that contains the convenience GUI utilities. I somehow missed the fact that you're linking with it, even though you don't use it.

Comment: Dan, if you're interested in another OpenCV/GTK+ related problem I just posted one recently. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Gtk, this was just logic and some experience with binaries. I'll have a look nevertheless.

Comment: Hi Alex. If the comment/answer from @DanMašek have helped you please accept his answer/upvote https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Considering you've installed Gtk+ 3 **after** building OpenCV, it's quite likely that it would have been built to work with Gtk+ 3. Since it complains, it suggests you already had some older version installed, and it uses that.

Hence, if you want to use the GUI convenience functions in OpenCV, you need to rebuild OpenCV, making sure it is built with with the correct version of Gtk+.

However, since you're providing your own GUI, it would seem that you don't really need to use that part of OpenCV. Since you have built OpenCV as individual modules, you could simply not link with `opencv_highgui` in order to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but in python I have resolve it by append this two lines in the head of the main python file. It will specify only version, which you want when your environment have many version of GTK. Good lucks !

```
import gi  
gi.require_version('Gtk', '2.0')
```