# Can we compile both OpenCv-3.3.0 and GTK+3 with gcc using C code?

Tags: c, opencv, gcc, gtk, gtk3

I was looking for a C processing image library and find out that OpenCV library was the most convenient (According to people advices). So I decided to install the latest version, but when I tried to include it to my existing GTK+ (C) project, it gave me compiling errors :

```
undefined reference to cvRound
```

Exact message is :

```
$ gcc ./bin/app.o \ 
    $(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0) \
    $(pkg-config --libs pango) \
    $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0) \
    $(pkg-config --libs gmodule-2.0) \
    $(pkg-config --libs opencv) -o bin/app

./bin/app.o : Dans la fonction « cvPointFrom32f » :
app.c:(.text+0x557) : référence indéfinie vers « cvRound »
app.c:(.text+0x56d) : référence indéfinie vers « cvRound »
./bin/app.o : Dans la fonction « cvReadInt » :
app.c:(.text+0xe74) : référence indéfinie vers « cvRound »
./bin/app.o : Dans la fonction « cvEllipseBox » :
app.c:(.text+0x10dc) : référence indéfinie vers « cvRound »
app.c:(.text+0x10fe) : référence indéfinie vers « cvRound »
collect2: error: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make: *** [Makefile:38: bin/app] Error 1
```

So, I wanted to know, what can I do in order to use OpenCV AND GTK+ (As I don't need OpenCV UI because I already have mine) ?

I also tried to remove gcc by g++ (But this does not solve the problem either) and now it compiles, BUT when I try to run my application using :

```
$ ./app
```

I got

```
Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
```

I think I'm giving up on installing OpenCV to make it works with GTK+...

P.S: If you have any advice or library recommandations (C) I take it.

Comment: Did you tried with `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`? Is `libopencv-dev` installed? (I guess so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OpenCV version is most likely built using GTK+ 2, so when you link a GTK+ 3 application with OpenCV, symbols conflict. You can't have both versions in the same process, as stated in the error message. So you just need to rebuild OpenCV with GTK+ 3 support enabled.

BTW, you don't need to specify every dependency explicitely when calling pkg-config, just toplevel ones. So `$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 opencv)` should be enough.

Comment: How do I do to rebuild OpenCV with GTK+ 3 ? I have actually no idea, and it seems to be the better thing to do in my case.

Comment: Then another option is to not link with the `opencv_highgui` library, as you're using your own gui: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112339/518853

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion https://forum.opencv.org/t/building-opencv-with-opengl-build-error/7106/11 . In **OpenCV**, currently, **Gtk-3** and **OpenGL** cannot be enabled at the same time. However, from [How do you do 3D rendering in Gtk+ using OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201843/how-do-you-do-3d-rendering-in-gtk-using-opengl), **Gtk-3** and **OpenGL** can be integrated...